# Django filter queryset if field exists

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

In my custom manager I would like to filter queryset if only this field has value:

```
class PropertyManager(gis_models.GeoManager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(PropertyManager,self).get_queryset().filter(active=True, valid_until__gte = datetime.now())
```

The problem is that `valid_until` field is not required and may be null. So I would like my manager to filter objects (`valid_until__gte = datetime.now()`) only if this field's value has been set during object creation. If this value is null, I would only like the manager to use the first filter (`active=True`).

Is it possible to make such raw SQL IF statements in Django ? I am using Mysql db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Q object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) to combine your lookup.

You can do filter to find objects which has `valid_date > now() OR valid_date=None` as

```
.filter(Q(valid_until__gte = datetime.now()) | Q(valid_until=None))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible to exclude all not-wanted results, so in your case:

```
.filter(active=True).exclude(valid_until__lt=datetime.now())
```

This will exclude all results where `valid_until` is set an lower than `datetime.now()`, so None-values will be returned as well!